# Django prefetch_related failing to pass data to template

Tags: django, django-templates

I have two Django models:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80, null=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=False)

class Image(models.Model):
    url = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True, null=False)
    product = models.ForeignKey('Product', related_name='images')
```

I have a specific set of products.  Each product has multiple images.  The initial call looks something like:

```
product_list = product_list.filter(is_active=True).prefetch_related('images')
```

The product_list then gets whittled down depending on filters that are applied.

When I try to use the product_list within the display layer (template), I iterate the list of products.  I can access all the product's fields *except*  its images.

{{ product.images.0.id }}  ==> empty

{{ product.images }}  ==> returns Image.None

Running the code through the debugger, I can see the Image SQL query being executed, it's just that none of the data is passed to the template.  There definitely is data there, as I can verify the query running it through my SQL client.  Does any one know why this is happening?  How do I get access to the Images for a given product?

Answer (score 11):

I solved my issue.  The prefetched data had to accessed like: product.images.all.0.id